# Display data extracted from an API - making a App in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to extract data through an API which is being done fine, however, its not getting displayed. Debugging shows correct result but the result is just not getting displayed. When I do Hot Reload, only then it shows the data.

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './ui/klimatic.dart';

void main() async {

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Klimatic',
    home: Klimatic(),
  ));
}
```

util/utils.dart (including API URL)

```
//https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lahore&appid=<USERS-PERSONAL-APPID>&units=metric
final appId = "fasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfafsaf";
final defaultCity = "Lahore";
```

ui/klimatic.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../util/utils.dart' as utils;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

// ======== FIRST SCREEN ===========
class Klimatic extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KlimaticState createState() => _KlimaticState();
}

class _KlimaticState extends State<Klimatic> {
 // ===== CALLING FUNCTION FOR SECOND SCREEN =======
  String _cityEntered;
  Future _goToChangeCity(BuildContext context) async {
    Map results = await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<Map>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeCity();
    }));

    if(results != null && results.containsKey('info')){
      _cityEntered = results['info'];
    }else{
      print('nothing');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Klimatic'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        actions: <Widget>[
         IconButton(
           icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
           onPressed: () { _goToChangeCity(context); }
         )
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Image.asset('images/umbrella.png', width: 490.0, height: 1200.0, fit: BoxFit.fill,)
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 30, 0),
// ==== THIS WILL PRINT CITY NAME ON TOP ====
            child: Text('${_cityEntered == null ? utils.defaultCity : _cityEntered}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.9,),),),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Image.asset('images/light_rain.png'),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 350, 0, 0),
// ==== THIS WILL PRINT TEMPERATURE OF CITY =====
            child: updateTempWidget('${_cityEntered == null ? utils.defaultCity : _cityEntered}'),//Text('${_weather['temp']} C', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 49.9, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
          )

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ====== SECOND SCREEN ==========
class ChangeCity extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _nameController = TextEditingController();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Change City'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Image.asset('images/white_snow.png', width: 490.0, height: 1200.0, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
          ),
          ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: _nameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Input City Name'
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context,
                    {'info' : _nameController.text}
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Get Weather')
              )
            ],
          )
          ]
      )
    );
  }
}

Future<Map> getWeather(String cityTemp) async {
  String apiUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$cityTemp&appid=${utils.appId}&units=metric";
  print(apiUrl);
  http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
  //print(response.body);
  return json.decode(response.body);

}

Widget updateTempWidget(String city) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: getWeather(city),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map> snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          Map content = snapshot.data;
          return Container(
            child: new ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(content['main']['temp'].toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 49.9, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(content['main']['humidity'].toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.9, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(content['main']['pressure'].toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.9, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }else{
          return Container();
        }
  }
  );
}
```

This is my json output from API.

```
    {
      "coord": {
        "lon": 67.08,
        "lat": 24.91
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "clear sky",
          "icon": "01d"
        }
      ],
      "base": "stations",
      "main": {
        "temp": 34,
        "feels_like": 35,
        "temp_min": 34,
        "temp_max": 34,
        "pressure": 1006,
        "humidity": 49
      },
      "visibility": 7000,
      "wind": {
        "speed": 5.1,
        "deg": 270
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 5
      },
      "dt": 1589191993,
      "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 7576,
        "country": "PK",
        "sunrise": 1589158175,
        "sunset": 1589205996
      },
      "timezone": 18000,
      "id": 1174872,
      "name": "Karachi",
      "cod": 200
    }
```

Comment: Your example:
```{"coord":{"lon":67.08,"lat":24.91},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":34,"feels_like":35,"temp_min":34,"temp_max":34,"pressure":1006,"humidity":49},"visibility":7000,"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":270},"clouds":{"all":5},"dt":1589191993,"sys":{"type":1,"id":7576,"country":"PK","sunrise":1589158175,"sunset":1589205996},"timezone":18000,"id":1174872,"name":"Karachi","cod":200}```

Does not include the key "info"

Comment: I'm generating that from the other screen ```class ChangeCity``` like this. ```FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context,
                    {'info' : _nameController.text}
                  );
                },```... in the above example see the json part. ```"name": "Karachi"```. so it is going to be like ```'info' : 'Karachi'```. I'd like to reiterate that I'm getting the result fine as this json is the output I'm getting, but I'm unable to force the screen to show this output.

Comment: Ok, I see. Could you include the full code for your two screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setState()` after retrieving the value from the other screen. This is to tell the framework that the state has changed and that it needs to redraw stuff. Or, as the documentation says: "Notify the framework that the internal state of this object has changed."

I think it will work if you change to this:

```
Future _goToChangeCity(BuildContext context) async {
    Map results = await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<Map>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeCity();
    }));

    if(results != null && results.containsKey('info')){
      setState(() { _cityEntered = results['info']; });
    }else{
      print('nothing');
    }
  }
```

Comment: ahhhh... How in the world did I miss that... strange. Thanks alot.

Comment: In this code, can you please guide me how to call the function ```getWeather(city)``` inside ```initState()``` which I'm calling here. ```Widget updateTempWidget(String city) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: getWeather(city),```. I was trying like this but the variable ```weather``` in not accessible inside the ```updateTempWidget``` function. ```Future<Map> weather;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final String cityName = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    final weather = getWeather(cityName);
  }```

Comment: You can't do async work in initState, but see one of my previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640723/flutter-camera-plugin
The solution in that answer is a good solution for this, I think.