# Flutter - availableCameras() returns empty list

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera, ios-camera

This code was working just fine a while ago, but is now misbehaving for no reasons, I tried to re-install the app 2 times, but didn't worked, what might be causing it? It was giving me a list of available cameras before, but after a hot-restart, the code is constantly breaking.

```
 Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  cameras = await availableCameras(); // returns an empty list, which it shouldn't because I'm using a real device which has two physical cameras, all dependencies are added, all permissions are allowed.

  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}
```

Note: The error is coming when I try to access the cameras list, but it was able to access it two hours ago, why is it returning an empty list right now?

Comment: Are you showing all relevant code? What happens when you comment out the line with "cameras = ...". Are you accessing this list anywhere else, even when it is empty?

Comment: @JoRa Yes, I'm getting this error when accessing cameras list in a different page, before an hour it was returning a non-empty list, but right now I'm getting this range error meaning that the list is empty. And also, I'm not using an emulator, I'm using a physical device (Android).

Comment: `availableCameras()` is a future method. It is not empty, since it is async `cameras` value may get used before assigning. This [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640723/flutter-camera-plugin) will help you

Comment: @ShashankGb and hence I'm using await, that should not run my app before the list is returned, and that was working perfectly fine, but now, the returned (awaited) list of avaiable cameras is turning out be empty and there are no debug messages for that even.

Comment: Ok, i didn't noticed await. Can you share the physical device info in which you are running this

Comment: @ShashankGb Sure, I'm using Samsung J6 which currently has Android 10 (my minimumSdkVersion is 21 inside the gradle, so that is compatible for the camera plugin of Flutter), and my phone has a front camera and a rear camera, both working, so the list above should have 2 items, you can check about that method (availableCameras) on pub.dev's camera package, also my app was working just fine a while ago as I have mentioned, but currently I'm struggling to proceed with the existing code.

Comment: @ShashankGb I tried to improve the code by awaiting for the availableCameras() method inside the screen where I need to use the cameras list, but then the method is executing forever (23 mins and counting), and never returning the list. Lol, is this the end of my Flutter journey?

Comment: Interesting, can you share the entire code in dartpad or somewhere so that I can repro. Because I can't find anything wrong here

Comment: @ShashankGb There's no point in sharing you my code, because it'll waste your time as the code is already being tested by me plenty of times. I had to switch to another package (flutter_camera) and also change some of it's source code (UI part mostly) locally in order to get desired results. The flutter_camera is working, I can access both of my cameras without needing to call any "availableCameras" that means it's surely the camera package's internal error, the package is relatively newer, so might not be mature enough at this point. By the way, thanks a lot for trying to help till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is most probably due to the "camera" plugin's internal working or due to Android OS's security reasons or something like that. The camera package is new, so you can expect such behaviors, but there are bunch of other enhanced packages as well based on the original one.
In my case, I used "flutter_camera" and modified the source code as per my needs in order to achieve the desired UI, and it works pretty good.

Update: I found out that the error was indirectly connected to "compileSdkVersion" in my app/build.gradle being set to 33 which was required by a random flutter plugin, setting it to 29 allowed me to access my camera and successfully executed availableCameras() method too but then the plugin can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

For all of you that may have done the same error as me by copy-pasting "camera" code from pubdev,
keep in mind that the code of "camera" was made for being main page, wich means _cameras is initialised by :

```
List<CameraDescription> _cameras = <CameraDescription>[];
```

but it's the main() function role to fill it, so if you call CameraApp() from outside of the page, main will not be triggered, therefore you need to modify the class like this:

```
class CameraApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Default Constructor
  const CameraApp({Key? key, required this.cameras}) : super(key: key);

  final List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _cameras=cameras;
  return const MaterialApp(
      home: CameraExampleHome(),

    );
  }
}
```

and call it from another page with:

```
await availableCameras().then((value) => Navigator.push(context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => CameraApp(cameras: value))));
```

Like so the cameras are properly filled. That's my working solution.
Possible amelioration: Maybe the cameras list could be filled directly in CameraApp?